# Write a C# code to return a string with case of every letter reversed

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Do we have any proper function in C# to do it?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string s1 = textBox1.Text;
 }
```

Comment: Since this is almost certainly homework: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: the question is to translate "aBcDE" into "AbCde" right? No I don't think there is a inbuild method but I too think that this is homework - am I right? Anyway it's rather easy to build, strings implement IEnumerable<char> and if you look at the MSDN docs for char and string you will find all you need to do this yourself ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
string s1 = new string(
    textBox1.Text.Select(ch => char.IsLetter(ch) ? (char.IsUpper(ch) ?
                      char.ToLower(ch) : char.ToUpper(ch)) : ch).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public string RevString()
{
    var s = "TestThisString";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var arr = s.ToCharArray();

    foreach (var c in arr)
    {
        if (c.ToString() == c.ToString().ToLower())
        { sb.Append(c.ToString().ToUpper());}
        else
        { sb.Append(c.ToString().ToLower()); }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```